# Bash, running script with parameters from local to SSH HOST.

Tags: bash, variables, ssh, parameters, host

So i have problem with running my script 100% on host. The only way i found working with my case is

```
cat script.sh | ssh -tt nameofhost
```

and script.sh contain's

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo su anotheracc
cd /path/to/that/script
./thatscript.sh [my specific parameter eg. "7021"]
```

And my question is. How to make parameter(7021) not permament, but variable. It doesn't matter if i will have to have three or four files working on 1 script, it will improve my mobility so much.

How to make I/O redirect and also let let ./thatscript.sh execute it with this variable?

Comment: Why `-tt`? If your stdin is coming from a pipe, it can't be a TTY.

Comment: Because if i do -t or no option it says 
"Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal." 
And don't execute script

Comment: Not allocating a PTY is not an error -- in current conditions, it's actually *desirable*. There's no point to allocating a PTY for a program only needs stdin/stdout/stderr behaving as regular FIFOs.

Comment: Oh, `sudo su`. Right. **That** needs a TTY.

Comment: Moreover, the even bigger problem you have here is that you're expecting `sudo su` to apply to commands later in the same script. It doesn't work that way: It starts a *new and different* escalated shell, it doesn't change the permissions of the shell you already started.

Comment: Consequently, whether `sudo su` increases privileges of commands on subsequent lines read from `stdin` is very unreliable: It depends on whether the shell has read those lines before it reads the current one. (If it has, they're unavailable for the new shell started by `su` to read).

Comment: Yeee i found how to redirect I/O and tried to make it read a .txt in local shell and then insert it in SSH shell but that didn't work.

Comment: So better solution for this is make it all in one script. This are the steeps i need to do: I want to make Option menu at the Cases which is easy step, then if i chose 1, i want to connect to ssh, go to other user because only from him i can execute that script, execute that script with changing parameter at the end, because this script is written locally in the shell. And point is, i tried it with many combinations, some worked some no, but always i didn't have parameter but only "7234" permamently for test. It can't ask me for PW because in some cases ssh asked me for Password.

Comment: Could u explain me it more easily, because im beginning my journey with bash

Comment: Maybe ssh isn't the right approach here?  How about something like `sudo runuser -l $usr -c 'command-list orOtherScript'` ?